# How to write a recursive flat map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an object of nested route.

Any route **MAY** contains a list of route `childRoutes`.

I want to get the list of all the route that contains the key `menu`.

```js
const routes = [{
        "name": "userManagement",
        "childRoutes": [
          {
            "name": "blogManagement",
            "childRoutes": [
              {
                "name": "blog",  // <=== I want to have this route
                "menu": {
                  "role": 1020
                }
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            "name": "organizationList", // <=== and this one
            "menu": {
              "role": 1004
            }
          }

        ],
      }, { 
       "name": "test", 
   "menu": { "role": 4667 }
   }];

const deepFlatten = arr => [].concat(...arr.map(v => (Array.isArray(v) ? deepFlatten(v) : v)));

// Should handle nesting of route 
const links = deepFlatten(routes).filter((r) => !!r.menu); 

console.log('it should have a length of 3:', links.length === 3);
console.log('it should be blog:', links[0].name === 'blog');
console.log('it should be organizationList:', links[1].name === 'organizationList');
console.log('it should be test:', links[2].name === 'test');
```

The above snippet does not work recursively yet.

How can I do it recursively without any third-party library ?

Comment: Can a node contain both a menu key and a childnodes key?

Comment: @Glubus is there a reason not to assume it's possible?

Comment: Well the algorithm needs to take this into account. If you look at zfrisch' answer, you see that his algorithm terminates whenever it finds `menu`. If both keys are allowed to exist within the same node, you need to traverse the rest of the tree and see if the rest of the nodes along the route are also part of your result.

Comment: Yes, there's a reason to accept the possibility.  So, back to my original question, is there a reason not to assume it's possible?

Comment: There is reason to determine if it is impossible rather, because if you can truncate the rest of the childnodes of a node whenever it contains menu, you can skip a whole lot of executions which obviously implies better runtime.

Comment: @zfrisch version isn't taking in account the fact that route can have menu.

Comment: @BigDong okay, I'll update my answer, but this is a question I asked you before you deleted and reposted and you said that all `menu` items were found inside child routes.

Comment: I didn't noticed at this moment @zfrisch sorry. I've updated the code sample in order to show a table instead of an object, that make more sens now I can see.

Comment: If someone wants to grab my answer and adjust it that's fine https://jsfiddle.net/mv7892az/ - but I won't have time to look at it again until later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about this, seems to work.

```
const flatten = (routes) => {
    return routes.reduce((acc, r) => {
      if(r.childRoutes && r.childRoutes.length) {
        acc = acc.concat(flatten(r.childRoutes));
      } else {
        acc.push(r);
      }

      return acc;
    }, [])
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vv9odcxw/

Comment: This does pass the OP test cases on the presented data

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it does if you do `flatten(routes).filter((r) => !!r.menu)`

Comment: @BigDong yes, I did not clarify that (from your example code)

Comment: I re-ran this with 
`const links = flatten(routes);

console.log('it should have a length of 3:', links.length === 3);
console.log('it should be blog:', links[0].name === 'blog');
console.log('it should be organizationList:', links[1].name === 'organizationList');
console.log('it should be test:', links[2].name === 'test');`
These all return true

Comment: @BigDong I used your data. If the data does not represent all scenarios, you should have updated it when it was first noticed.

Answer (score 8):

@yBrodsky's answer can be adapted to isolate and exhibit the generic `flatMap` operation – here, you'll see that the routes flattened with much of the `reduce`-`map`-`concat` plumbing out of the programmer's way.

```js
// polyfill if you don't have it
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f)
{
  return this.reduce ((acc, x) =>
    acc.concat (f (x)), [])
}

// your data   
const routes =
    [ { name : "userManagement"
      , childRoutes :
            [ { name : "blogManagement"
              , childRoutes :
                    [ { name : "blog"
                      , menu : { role : 1020 }
                      }
                    ]
              }
            , { name : "organizationList"
              , menu : { role : 1004 }
              }
            ]
      }
    , { name : "test"
      , menu : { role : 4667 }
      }
    ]

// flat-mapped routes
const allChildRoutes =
  routes.flatMap (function loop (node) {
    if (node.childRoutes)
      return node.childRoutes.flatMap (loop)
    else
      return [node]
  })     
  
console.log (allChildRoutes)
```